# iphone how to make "To" field like sms applicaiton

Tags: iphone, sms

How can I can I make a "to" field like sms application?
Like, having a "+" button to right, when adding someone the name will be highlighted and clickable like the rounded rect etc.
Is there any built in framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, but see Three20's [TTMessageRecipientField](http://github.com/facebook/three20/blob/master/src/Three20UI/Sources/TTMessageRecipientField.m), which (I think) is supposed to be a clone of the UI.

Comment: thanks. Many times i found people refer to Three20, but I never tried yet. It is worth trying now.